# How to get the sum of all columns (large in number) in a seperate column for each row (mysql)?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, information-schema

I have a large table with 150 + columns and it holds numbers. The first column holds `text` values and the rest of the columns hold `int` values. I want to create a new column which holds the summed value of all columns in each row (excluding the first column which holds text). I don't want to enter the names of each and every column in the query as I will need to type about 150 + column names.

```
--------------------------------------------------------
name | physics | chemistry | maths | biology | summation
--------------------------------------------------------
n1   | 10      | 20        | 30    | 50      | 110
--------------------------------------------------------
n2   | 20      | 10        | 40    | 30      | 100
--------------------------------------------------------
```

this is a simple layout of my table, here there are only 4 columns holding the values to be summed. But in my case there are 150 + columns. And as shown in the sample I want to create the new column summation.

Comment: `I don't want to enter the names of each and every column in the query as I will need to type about 150 + column names`
Is that the only reason that you dont want to do that? What is wrong in writing the column names until it is very volatile table structure. You can describe that table and get in a spreadsheet and add `+` symbol in between.

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: Too many columns, have one row per subject instead.

Comment: @jarlh In my special case I need to find the sum of marks score in each subject. as physics -30, chemistry-30 and so on. so changing rows with columns and vice-versa will not solve my problem. I have about 7000 rows.

Comment: Have you try rotate 150+ columns to 150+ rows then use sum function?

Comment: select name ,physics + chem+maths+...as sum from table

Comment: @Utsav Thats fine. But I just want to know if there is a way in sql

Comment: If you don't want to enter the names of each columns in query, then ask somebody to do that. :D

Answer (score 0):

I've created a test table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_Test](
        [Name] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
        [physics] [int] NULL,
        [chemistry] [int] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And added some data into it.

Then I build a dynamic SQL and executes it:

```
declare  @sql varchar (MAX) = 'select Name, ('
declare  @ColName varchar (20) = ''

DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR 
  LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR 
select  c.COLUMN_NAME  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C where C.TABLE_NAME =  'Table_Test' and c.DATA_TYPE = 'int'
OPEN MY_CURSOR

FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @ColName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
   set @Sql  += '"' + @ColName + '" '  + ' + '
    --Do something with Id here
    ---PRINT @PractitionerId
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @ColName
END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR

set @Sql  += '0) as Total from Table_Test '
exec(@sql);
print @sql

--Wanted result
--select name, ("physics" + "chemistry" + 0) as Total from  [dbo].[Table_Test]
```

And here it si for MYSQL:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE Sums ( )

BEGIN

DECLARE SQlText nvarchar(10000);
DECLARE ColName varchar (20);

DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
  select  c.COLUMN_NAME  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C where C.TABLE_NAME =  'Table_Test' and c.DATA_TYPE = 'int';

open MY_CURSOR;

FETCH MY_CURSOR INTO ColName;

set SQlText = 'select Name, (';

start_loop: loop
  set SQlText =  concat( SQlText , '`' , ColName , '` '  , ' + ');  
  select  concat(SqlText, '0) as Total from Table_Test ') as '';
  FETCH MY_CURSOR INTO ColName;

end loop;

Close MY_CURSOR;

set @SQlText = concat(SqlText, '0) as Total from Table_Test ');
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQlText;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try by this simple way

```
SELECT t.*, SUM( IF(t.physics='',0,t.physics) + IF(t.chemistry='',0,t.chemistry) + ... so on) AS subtotal FROM TableName AS t GROUP BY t.id ORDER BY subtotal DESC
```